# ObjectDataSource Filtering on DateTime

Tags: asp.net

I am currently using `ObjectDataSource` filtering on my gridview control. The `ObjectDataSource` filtering works well with Date. However, if there is a column with timestamp, the `ObjectDataSource` filtering doesn't work at all.

For Example, if the column only contains the `DateTime` like '02/01/2011', the `ObjectDataSource` filtering works fine with the data. If the column contains the `Datetime` with the timestamp, '02/01/2011 10:30 AM', the user tried to filter it by entering '02/01/2011 10:30 AM' to filterexpression. the `ObjectDataSource` filter doesn't work at all. I was wondering if anyone can give me a hint on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [FilterExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.filterexpression.aspx) property of the ObjectDataSource.